# How to enable developer option in android kitkat programatically?

Tags: android

I want to enable developer options when android kitkat 4.4.2 is built from source. Is there any way?

If someone has tried this please let me know.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible. Developer mode is a system setting and cannot be modified with an app you create. Only system apps can tweak system setting.

Comment: i hoped i could do something in packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/DeviceInfoSettings.java

Answer (score 0):

1. On a regular device (Non Rooted Phone), with a regular app, you can't.
2. If you have a rooted phone and making a system application, you may follow this:

   ```
   Settings.Global.putInt(getContentResolver(), Global.ADB_ENABLED, 1);
   ```

   and use this permission:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>
   ```

   adding this permission in manifest you will get this error: **Permission is only granted to system apps**

Comment: Hi , I may be confusing with my question, i have kitkat source. I am building the source for a tablet. It is like an embedded device.

Comment: The requirement is, android should come with DEVELOPER OPTIONS before "About tablet" without clicking or tapping.

Answer (score 0):

Below one line comment did the trick,

```
else if (id == R.id.development_settings) {
             if (!showDev) {
             //    target.remove(i);
              }
```

in packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/Settings.java